# Youtube iframe API events not triggering when modifing DOM inside onYouTubeIframeAPIReady

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

For some reason, adding a DIV in onYouTubeIframeAPIReady to the player parent (or any of it ancestor) cause the player events not being fired.

No errors are shown in the inspect console.
Happens on all browsers.

Here's a fiddle using the basic example from YouTube with the additional addDivTo() function called from onYouTubeIframeAPIReady:
https://jsfiddle.net/hdavu6o9/

Is this a known bug, and is there a workaround available if it is?

HTML:

```
<body id='body'>
    <div id='gparent'>
        <div id='parent'>
            <div id="player"></div>
            <div id="sibling"></div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady called");
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
    
    addDivTo('parent'); // player events not triggered
    //addDivTo('gparent'); // player events not triggered
    //addDivTo('body'); //player events not triggered
    //addDivTo('sibling'); //works fine
  }

  function addDivTo(id){
      var ele = document.getElementById(id);
      ele.innerHTML += "<div class='thediv'>DIV added to " + id + "</div>";
      console.log("DIV added to " + id);
  }
```